# Distance in Hopf coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, spheres, hopf-fibration

I have been reading about Hopf coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hopf_coordinates) which parameterize points on $\mathbb{S}^3$ as follows:
\begin{align}
x_0 &= \cos \xi_1 \sin\eta \\
x_1 &= \sin \xi_1\sin\eta \\
x_2 &= \cos\xi_2 \cos\eta \\
x_3 &= \sin\xi_2\cos\eta
\end{align}
where $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\eta)\in [0,2\pi)\times[0,2\pi)\times [0,\pi/2)$. Is it known if there are any formulas for relating geodesic distances on $\mathbb{S}^3$ to expressions in these coordinates?

Comment: Has [this](https://folk.uib.no/ima083/bibliogr_files/ChMV-Hopf.pdf) some interest for you ?

Comment: I found it perhaps too sophisticated for my level of differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$If $\Vec{u}$ and $\Vec{u}'$ are points on the unit sphere in Euclidean $n$-space, they may be identified with unit vectors, and the geodesic distance between them is the angle they subtend at the origin:
$$d(\Vec{u}, \Vec{u}') = \arccos(\Vec{u} \cdot \Vec{u}').$$

[image: Geodesic distance on a unit sphere]

In your situation, taking $\Vec{u} = (x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ and $\Vec{u}' = (x_{0}', x_{1}', x_{2}', x_{3}')$ with
\begin{align*}
  x_{0} &= \cos\xi_{1} \sin\eta, & x_{0}' &= \cos\xi_{1}' \sin\eta', \\
  x_{1} &= \sin\xi_{1} \sin\eta, & x_{1}' &= \sin\xi_{1}' \sin\eta', \\
  x_{2} &= \cos\xi_{2} \cos\eta, & x_{2}' &= \cos\xi_{2}' \cos\eta', \\
  x_{3} &= \sin\xi_{2} \cos\eta, & x_{3}' &= \sin\xi_{2}' \cos\eta',
\end{align*}
the geodesic distance is
$$d(\Vec{u}, \Vec{u}') = \arccos(x_{0}x_{0}' + x_{1}x_{1}' + x_{2}x_{2}' + x_{3}x_{3}').$$

Comment: Thank you. When one writes out the actual formula, one finds a rather cumbersome expression of the arccosine of various products of trigonometric quantities. I was hoping that there was an easier expression.

Comment: That's right; generally the distance is a mess. The formulas will simplify to the increment of one of the angle coordinates if both points lie on a Hopf circle, but in general you get what you get.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include your observation w.r.t. the Hopf circle? That could still be useful for me.